# fields disappear in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online

This is an online 365 SharePoint client. On several of our sites there are Lists which have had fields disappear. On the lists view, the column is still there, but the item is gone from the new-item and edit forms. One of the disappearing fields was "Title". It was a required field so I'm surprised the form could be submitted, but it was. An ID# populates that field on the view for record created with the field missing.
Going to List Settings and opening and saving the field re-activates it on the forms. It is unknown how long the fix lasts.
(next day)The fix is still holding. But now I see that in the content type (Item) the Title field is set to "Hidden". I wonder how that happened? Two weeks ago I created a custom content type used at a different site, which inherits "Title" from the Item content type. I was pretty careful not to mess with any existing content types, but I wonder if that event caused my problem somehow.
Any idea what might be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Content Type problem. CT's inherit qualities from master (Site Setting) CTs. If the master CT has a field set to hidden CTs the inherit from it will also get the field set to hidden - although not necessarily always. It is possible to set the local CT different. Not sure how long it will stay different.